# Read a file or print a message in CMake

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to read a file's content and set a variable on the condition whether a file exists relative to the CMakeLists.txt script file. For example, I want to conditionally set an environment variable with the content of a file that resides on disk, and if it's not there I want to print a helpful message.

```
if (EXISTS pkgconfig-environment)
    file(READ pkgconfig-environment LOCAL_PKG_CONFIG_PATH)
    set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} ${LOCAL_PKG_CONFIG_PATH})
else()
    message("
    I hope you know what you're doing with your pkg-config.
")
endif ()
```

The logic above never detects the file `pkgconfig-environment`, and it instead always prints the message. The file can be read into a cmake variable, but only if it exists.

There are two problems: first, `file(READ ...)` will fail the build sometimes because the file doesn't exist (I don't care if it's a directory and it fails. That's not my use case). Second, the parameter expected in the call `if(EXISTS path)` should probably be an absolute path, but I wanted the file to be tested for existence relative to the CMakeLists.txt script file.

Given how clearly the documentation states that exists-checks are supposed to be absolute paths, it leads me to think there's some way to determine the absolute path of a file from a relative path near the CMakeLists.txt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the full path to the directory containing the **current** CMakeLists.txt file, use [`${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR.html):

```
if (EXISTS ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/pkgconfig-environment)
    file(READ ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/pkgconfig-environment LOCAL_PKG_CONFIG_PATH)
    set(ENV{PKG_CONFIG_PATH} ${LOCAL_PKG_CONFIG_PATH})
else()
    message("
    I hope you know what you're doing with your pkg-config.
")
endif ()
```